# AWS Elastic Beanstalk container_commands in Python 3.4 Docker Container

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a `Django 1.6` application running on Python 3.4 that I’d like to deploy on `AWS Elastic Beanstalk`, so I’ve selected “Preconfigured - Docker/Python” (i.e., Python 3.4) as my configuration but deployments fail on the `container_command` to run `django-admin.py`. The same placeholder app bundle runs as expected on the “Preconfigured/Python” configuration (i.e., Python 2.7) without error.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-container_commands) `.ebextension` config `container_commands` are run after the application and web server have been set up and the application version file has been extracted, but before the application is deployed. That appears to be the case for the Python 2.7 container but not the Python 3.4 Docker container.

To test the theory, I added a script to my bundle to peek at the environment and executed it as a `container_command`. The Python 2.7 container uses Python 2.7, has pip packages installed from `requirements.txt`, and finds `django-admin.py` as expected. The Python 3.4 Docker container, however, uses Python 2.6 during the container_command phase and thus doesn’t have the environment set up to find `django-admin.py` or installed pip packages.

How can I get the the Preconfigured - Docker/Python (3.4) container to execute `container_commands` in the intended environment? Is there a step missing to activate the container and/or it’s virtualenv before triggering `container_commands`?

Answer (score 1):

AWS Support pointed me to adding a custom Dockerfile.  I used my Dockerfile's ENTRYPOINT to override the default from the base image so I could slip in my own script to trigger the syncdb command.

ref: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=595630

Comment: Isn’t this undesirable, since it would lead to every machine in your pool running the startup scripts for something that you maybe want to only be `leader_only`?